# How to pause and resume execution of a php script

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to make a twitter bot that will scrape the followers of a given twitter account.

Because twitter has rate limits so that you can't retrieve more than a certain amount of IDS at which point it does not allow you to query for a period of 15 mins, at the moment I am stuck trying to figure out how to make the execution of my script pause for those 15 mins then resume once the period is over.

I have tried everything from the sleep command, to implementing a simple timer that echos the elapsed time every few seconds. None of these techniques work and the script times out.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to implement the functionality i am after. Something like what Manageflitter does.

Comment: The script can be stopped and then resumed after 15 minutes with a cron knowing which is the next id to fetch`

Comment: How do you pass the variable between executions of the script?

Comment: @JoshMeth You may [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) (or [`json`](http://php.net/json-encode)) variables as array and put to database, to fetch later between script calls.

Comment: Thx for the hints. But I was wondering how do you stop the cron from running once all the usernames have been scraped. As per my understanding of cron it runs indefinately at a set interval. Is there anyway to delete the cron once execution has completed? Any ideas how I(the user) can tell that all followers have been scraped?